# Practical guidelines to improve new Angular App Lighthouse score?

Tags: angular, performance, progressive-web-apps, lighthouse

I am trying to develop a simple PWA, in fact I already did, but after I deployed it on Netlify and ran Lighthouse, it performed quite poorly on Performance and Best Practices, despite being a really simple spa app with 4 pages.
Then I started again with a clean slate,

```
    ng new AngularApp --enable-ivy
    cd AngularApp
    ng add @angular/pwa
    ng build --prod --aot --vendor-chunk --common-chunk --delete-output-path --buildOptimizer
    http-server-spa dist/AngularApp index.html 8080
```

being Angular and Lighthouse both Google products I expected an almost perfect score on a new application with no functionalities, instead I got

- 84 Performance
- 95 Accessibility
- 86 Best Practices
- 91 SEO
- 3/3 3/3 5/7 PWA

Best practices lost some points I think because I did not use https to test the production build, that's ok, but performance had Fist Contentful Paint, First Meaningful Paint, First CPU Idle, all yellow taking more than 3 seconds, and Max Potential First Input Delay red at 390 ms.
How am I supposed to improve these bottlenecks, and especially keep that value low as I add more functionalities to my application?

Comment: Every single app and settup is different. The hints given in Lighthouse are the best for your particular situation. Once you use a HTTPS server that is (or is similar to) your final server then look at those hints.

Comment: If you need an HTTPS server for testing, there are free ones out there like https://Glitch.me